# send datagridview item to another form

Tags: c#, datagridview

hey i wrote below code to send my datagridview value seleted row to another form but i got this error my event is double content click and i dont know why this happened

```
Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index

using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication12
{
     public partial class Form5 : Form
    {
         public Form5()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form5_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            tblClassTableAdapter.Fill(dataSet1.tblClass);

        }

        private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {

    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.tblClassTableAdapter.FillBy1(this.dataSet1.tblClass, textBox1.Text);


    }

    private void dataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        new Form6(int.Parse(dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString())).Show();
    }
}
```

and my form 6

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication12
{
    public partial class Form6 : Form
    {

        int classid;
        private string p;
        public Form6(int myid)
        {
            classid = myid;
            InitializeComponent();
        }



        public Form6(string p)
        {
            // TODO: Complete member initialization
            this.p = p;
        }

        public void Form6_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            textBox1.Text = classid.ToString();

        }

        public DataGridViewRow dataGridViewRow { get; set; }
    }
}
```

thank you guys for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DataGridViewCellEventArgs has two important args for you:
e.rowIndex, e.columnIndex which specifying in which cell you pressed.

By the way, you are trying to parse Int from cell, surround it with try/catch for case the parse fails.

try this code instead:

```
try {
    if (e.ColumnIndex > -1 && e.RowIndex > -1)
        new Form6(int.Parse(dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex,e.RowIndex].Value.ToString())).Show();
}
catch (Exception ex) {
    MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message);
}
```

I think it should help you, mark as answered if yes.

Comment: this is good until  u click on first column if u clock another columns agian will crash

Comment: it will crash when ColumnIndex or RowIndex are the headeers (their value will be -1) editing my answer to avoid this

Comment: ty i chnage it to this and finally worked (e.ColumnIndex > -1 && e.ColumnIndex < 1)